# ECS Service Disovery vs ECS App Mesh for internal communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, service-discovery, aws-app-mesh

I have setup microservices in AWS ECS [ec2]. Currently, the containers are communicating over public faced ALB. I would like to establish internal communication between them.

I'm considering the following ECS in-built options i.e.,

**1. App Mesh**

**2. Service Discovery**

I would like to know Which one is better?